# Prolog Predicate to return true when two people have same hobby

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I want to write a Prolog predicate that returns true when two people have the same hobby, without using negation. I have the following database:

```
likes(john,movies). 
likes(john,tennis). 
likes(john,games). 
likes(karl,music). 
likes(karl,running). 
likes(peter,swimming).
likes(peter,movies). 
likes(jacob,art). 
likes(jacob,studying). 
likes(jacob,sleeping). 
likes(mary,running). 
likes(mary,sleeping). 
likes(sam,art). 
likes(sam,movies).
```

I came up with the following predicate:

```
same_hobby(X,Y) :-
   likes(X,Z),
   likes(Y,Z).
```

However, this predicate is also true when `X` equals `Y` and I do not want this to be the case. Can anyone help me find a solution? A small explanation would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Simply use `dif/2`: This predicate is true *iff* its arguments are different. So: `same_hobby(X, Y) :- dif(X, Y), likes(X, Hobby), likes(Y, Hobby).`

Comment: Do keep in mind that prolog predicates don't return anything. They just succeed or fail.

Comment: @Enigmativity or sometimes they go off into never-never land... :p

Comment: @lurker - Very true. If only we could write a program that would prove if they would finish or not. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the predicate **dif/2** , that is, dif(Term1, Term2) that means that Term1 have to differ from Term2, otherwise it will fail.
Your rule will become:

```
same_hobby(X,Y) :-
            likes(X,Z),
            likes(Y,Z),
            dif(X,Y).
```

Cause dif/2 is a completely pure predicate, you can also write this as

```
same_hobby(X,Y) :-
            dif(X,Y),
            likes(X,Z),
            likes(Y,Z).
```

That means that, if X differs from Y then reduce the goal likes(X,Z), likes(Y,Z), fail otherwise.

Comment: This will yield wrong results when you use it for the most general query `?- same_hobby(X, Y).`. Use `dif/2` instead. It is a pure predicate that works correctly in all directions.

Comment: or, just move \= **after** X and Y have been **instantiated**

Answer (score 2):

You can use the predicate `dif/2` to state that `X` and `Y` must not be equal:

```
same_hobby(X, Y) :-
    likes(X, Z),
    likes(Y, Z),
    dif(X, Y).
```

This makes it so the interpreter recognizes that `X` and `Y` need to be two different entities in order for the `same_hobby/2` predicate to be true.

Comment: Is there any way to make it so that if `X` and `Y` share multiple hobbies, it still only returns true once?