# One common hobby between two persons in Prolog

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif

I found this old question ( [Prolog Predicate to return true when two people have same hobby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34133904/prolog-predicate-to-return-true-when-two-people-have-same-hobby?answertab=active#tab-top) ) for writing some code to find the same hobby between two persons using dif. I have a similar situation, to display the names of two persons that have the same hobbies,but the hobbies element is defined as a list. Whatever I try it doesn't seem to work, any ideas would be appreciated.

This is what I have so far:

```
one_common_hobby(P1,P2):-
   dif(P1,P2),
   person(P1,_,_,hobbies([H|Tail])),
   person(P2,_,_,hobbies([H|Tail])),
   member(P1,Tail),
   member(P2,Tail).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, suppose the predicate `person` is defined as follows:

```
person(ann, hobbies([fishing, pottery, chess])).
person(bob, hobbies([parkour, painting, origami])).
person(coy, hobbies([hunting, fishing, parkour, chess])).
```

To find two different persons (`P1` and `P2`) who have a common hobby you must:

- Access the list of hobbies of the first person (`H1`).
- Access the list of hobbies of the second person (`H2`).
- Check if there is at least one hobby `X` that belongs simultaneously to lists `H1` and `H2`.

```
have_common_hobby(P1, P2) :-
    dif(P1, P2),
    person(P1, hobbies(H1)),
    person(P2, hobbies(H2)),
    once( ( member(X, H1),
            member(X, H2) ) ).
```

Example:

```
?- have_common_hobby(A, B).
A = ann,
B = coy ;
A = bob,
B = coy ;
A = coy,
B = ann ;
A = coy,
B = bob ;
false.
```